# Regex to get matches with overlapping characters

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have a data frame that I would like to extract specific words from. The words I need to extract are from a list that I am referencing, however since the strings in the list have overlapping characters, I am getting things multiple times. How can I avoid this to have a clean out put where it matches to the exact string in the list only once, and if there are more than one element found in the string, only get the first occurrence?. I've attached an example below where the column 'match' is the desired result.

Thank you.

`word_list = ['ok', 'ok z', 'ok zz', 'ok zzz']`

| Words | match |
| --- | --- |
| xxxxx xx xxxx ok zzz xxxx ok zzz xx | ok zzz |
| xxxx xxxx xx xxxx ok z xxxx xx x | ok z |
| xxx xx x xxxx ok zzz xxx xxx ok z xx | ok zzz |

Answer (score 1):

I would sort the word list in descending order of their lengths so that we try to first match/extract the word with maximum overlap.

```
pat = '(%s)' % '|'.join(sorted(word_list, key=len, reverse=True))
df['match'] = df['Words'].str.extract(pat)
```

---

```
                                  Words   match
0   xxxxx xx xxxx ok zzz xxxx ok zzz xx  ok zzz
1      xxxx xxxx xx xxxx ok z xxxx xx x    ok z
2  xxx xx x xxxx ok zzz xxx xxx ok z xx  ok zzz
```

Comment: I use this trick a lot, but it's only really viable for small lists of words, then it becomes very slow ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you have many strings in the list, an efficient method is to build a [trie](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), you can do so manually or use a module (e.g. [`trieregex`](https://github.com/ermanh/trieregex)) to build it from your list.

Manually (not optimized):

```
pattern = '(ok(?: (?:z(?:z(?:z)?)?)?)?)'
df['match'] = df['Words'].str.extract(pattern)
```

Automatically:

```
# pip install trieregex
from trieregex import TrieRegEx as TRE

pattern = TRE(*word_list).regex()
# 'ok(?:\\ z(?:zz?)?)?'

df['match'] = df['Words'].str.extract(f'({pattern})')
```

Output:

```
                                  Words   match
0   xxxxx xx xxxx ok zzz xxxx ok zzz xx  ok zzz
1      xxxx xxxx xx xxxx ok z xxxx xx x    ok z
2  xxx xx x xxxx ok zzz xxx xxx ok z xx  ok zzz
```